# At what pressure ratio did the fuel turbopumps of the F1 and J2 operate?

Tags: rockets, engine-design, engines, turbomachinery, turbopump

I would like to know the operating points of the fuel-turbo-pumps used in the Saturn rocket engine. (From what I could learn via google, the turbo pump went under the name Mark III) 
Is there any information on the pressure ratio of these pumps?

[image: markIII]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the monograph [NASA SP-8107 Turbopump Systems for Liquid Rocket Engines](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19750012398.pdf) (table II) :

The F1 fuel (RP-1) pump had an inlet pressure of 45 psi and an outlet pressure of 1856 psi.

The J2 fuel (Hydrogen) pump had an inlet pressure of 30 psi and an outlet pressure of 1238 psi.

Comment: Thanks, great resource. The NTRS version contain the table in better quality.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the higher quality version. I've corrected the numbers based on that.