# What is the inlet and outlet pressure of Merlin LOX/RP-1 turbopump?

Tags: rockets, falcon-9, pressure, turbopump

I got the inlet and outlet pressure of Saturn V engines turbopumps [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/22625/at-what-pressure-ratio-did-the-fuel-turbopumps-of-the-f1-and-j2-operate), but I couldn't find the turbopump pressure of the Merlin engine of Falcon 9.